# How to solving the ODE $\frac{dp}{dt}=-\frac{\lambda}{p}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

$p=p(t)$ is a function about $t$. I try to do so:
$$
\frac{dp}{dt}=-\frac{\lambda}{p}~\Rightarrow ~p dp=-\lambda dt~
\Rightarrow~\int p dp=\int -\lambda dt
~\Rightarrow~ \frac{1}{2}p^2=-\lambda t
~\Rightarrow~ p^2=-2\lambda t
$$

But the answer of book is $p^2=1-2\lambda t$ ,I don't know why there is 1.
The question is from the change of Einstein manifold under Ricci flow.

Comment: Well, you've forgot about constant of integration :) so the general solution to your problem is $\frac{1}{2} p^2 = C - \lambda t$. The constant $C$ should be determined from IVP. Is there any stated IVP in the book?

Comment: @ Evgeny yes, I miss it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution of the ODE has an integration constant : $p^2=-2\lambda t +c$ and the value $c=1$ correspond to the inital condition $p^2=1$.